# Sum of rows that satisfy a calculated measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

All.

I have a set of data that includes the following:

- Store Name
- Survey ID
- Number of surveys per store
- Score

Each survey has a score, and then the overall score for that store is calculate as an average.

**The score is a calculated measure based off 3 other calculated measures.**  These are created as below:

`Overall Score 1 = CALCULATE(CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Score 1]), 'All Detail'[Score 1] = 5) / (COUNT('Table'[Score 1]))) * 100`

`Overall Score 2 = CALCULATE(CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Score 2]), 'All Detail'[Score 2] = 5) / (COUNT('Table'[Score 2]))) * 100`

`Overall Score 3 = CALCULATE(CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Score 3]), 'All Detail'[Score 3] = 5) / (COUNT('Table'[Score 3]))) * 100`

`Score = ([Overall Score 1] + [Overall Score 2] + [Overall Score 3])/3`

I am wanting to count how many stores have beat a target score.

Currently I have a calculated measure which indicates that the store has beat the target:

`Achieved = IF([Score] >= 60, 1, 0)`

This works well on a cube at Store level, telling me that the average score for the store is over 60 or not, as below:

[image: Example data]

However, I am struggling to get the total of stores that have achieved target. In the example above the total would be 3 stores.

I have tried to create a filter measure as below:

`Total Achieved = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table', [Achieved] = 1))`

However, this brings back the number of surveys per store that have beat the target. Examples below:

[image: Store level detail]

[image: Survey level detail]

As you can see the `Total Achieved` calculated measure works well at a survey level but this is not the desired output.

Example of what I am looking for as the output below:

[image: Desired output]

Any advice would be appreciated. I have tried to use calculated columns but with no luck.

Comment: You have to use average score in the Achieved measure. This happens because table uniquely identifying multiple rows unless you introduce an aggregation

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Score variable is also a calculated measure, and I can't seem to be able to use average on it.

Comment: will you please be able to tell me How was that Score calculated?

Comment: It is a combination of three other calculated measures. I shall edit my original post now with how they are calculated.

Comment: I think i got the answer. No need to publish the queries. Create a summarize table (Calculate table) and then use the Archived measure on that summarize table this will give you the expected outcome.

Comment: I'm quite new to Power BI, would you be able to explain the steps to create a summarised table that you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the expected behavior of table visual first step is to create a [summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax) table as below. Here I have only group by from ‘Table'[Store] use your own grouping conditions.
s

```
sumtable = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
    
         SUMMARIZE(
    
              ‘Table’,
    
              ‘Table'[Store],
            
         ),
    
         ”Surveys”,SUM(Table[Surveys]),
         "Score" ,[Score]
    
    )
```

After that for the above summarize table create the measure as below

```
Achieved = IF(sumtable[Score] >= 60, 1, 0)
```

This will ensure your results.

Comment: Unfortnualy, this has not worked as desired. 
When creating the measure for Achieved as above, I get the following error:

```A single value for column 'Score' in table 'sumtable' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count or sum to get a single result.```

Comment: Hi cannot see the error

Comment: Have edited the comment.

Comment: Will you be able to come for a chat?

Comment: Please join using this link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244281/power-bi-visual-running-total-adds-up

Comment: I have joined the chat.

Comment: Hi are you there? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244281/power-bi-visual-running-total-adds-up